# How to update a state which is a array of objects?

Tags: reactjs

My state is as follows

```
this.state = {
            todos: [{
                title: 'asas',
                status: 'incomplete',
                uuid: 11
            }, {
                title: 'asas',
                status: 'incomplete',
                uuid: 12

            }, {
                title: 'asas',
                status: 'complete',
                uuid: 13

            }],

            currentTab: "Show All"
        }
```

and whenever a user clicks on any of the todo items's checkBox i want to update the state status of the checkbox and i have written the following code for it

```
 this.state.todos.map(todo => {
            if (todo.uuid === uuid) todo.status = (todo.status === 'complete') ? 'incomplete' : 'complete'
        });
        this.forceUpdate();
```

Is Using forceUpdate a good approach here? as i have updating only a single value inside an array of objects. Is there a better solution for this problem?

Comment: You must create a new state object and set it via `this.setState`. `forceUpdate` is **never** a good approach for anything.

Comment: this.state.todos.map(todo => {
            if (todo.uuid === uuid) todo.status = (todo.status === 'complete') ? 'incomplete' : 'complete'
        });
       
        let todos = this.state.todos;
         this.setState({ todos });

Comment: is this okay then or should i make another object using spread operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either of the following will call setState with the updated state without modifying the current state.

https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/immutableupdatepatterns#inserting-and-removing-items-in-arrays

**using the spread operator:**

edit.. actually, this is the hard way 8)
see https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/immutableupdatepatterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  const idx = prevState.todos.findIndex(todo => todo.uuid === uuid);
  return {
    todos: [
      ...prevState.todos.slice(0, idx),
      {
        ...prevState.todos[idx],
        status: prevState.todos[idx].status === "complete" ? "incomplete" : "complete",
      }
      ...prevState.todos.slice(idx + 1),
    ]
  }
});
```

**or using immer:**

```
import produce from "immer";

this.setState(prevState => {
  const idx = prevState.todos.findIndex(todo => todo.uuid === uuid);
  return produce(prevState, draft => {
    draft.todos[idx].status = prevState.todos[idx].status === "complete" ? "incomplete" : "complete"
  });
});
```